# Spring Jpa Repositories - Orm.xml

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Jpa Repositories.

I don't want to define my "named queries" in java classes (entities or repositories). I would like to define my "named queries" in different xml files (like orm.xml).

```
.... XML FILE ....
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

   <named-query name="MyEntity.findByField1">
      <query>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT m
        FROM MyEntity m
        WHERE
            m.field1 = :field1
                    ]]>
      </query>
   </named-query>                                 
</entity-mappings>



.... REPOSITORY CODE ....
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String>
{
   public Optional<MyEntity> findByField1(@Param("field1") String field1);
}
```

But my repositories are not finding the xml files with my named queries. How do I configure spring-data-jpa to use these xml files? I do not have a persistence.xml.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a property called "mappingResources" for "entityManagerFactory" bean. It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Since your `MyEntity` already has `field1` property inside using findByField1 as the Repository method name might be confusing. Change the orm.xml as following and place it inside META-INF/orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd">

   <named-query name="MyEntity.findByField1OrmXml">
      <query>
        <![CDATA[
        SELECT m
        FROM MyEntity m
        WHERE
            m.field1 = :field1
                    ]]>
      </query>
   </named-query>                                 
</entity-mappings>
```

And change the Repository as following

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, String>
{
   public Optional<MyEntity> findByField1OrmXml(@Param("field1") String field1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Sorry but I'm afraid I have not explained myself well. My problem is that the name of my xml file is not orm.xml, so my named queries are not found. How do I specify than my mapping resource file is for example "my-named-queries.xml"?

Comment: I have found what I was looking for. There is a property called "mappingResources" for "entityManagerFactory" bean. I'm going to test it.